# When exactly are onclose and onerror called for a WebSocket?

Tags: javascript, redux

With regard to the Websocket class, when should I expect `onerror` to be called, when should I expect `onclose` to be called and when should I expect both to be called? For example, if I try to connect to a non existing server I get both an onerror and an onclose, as follows:

```
Event {isTrusted: true, type: "error", target: WebSocket, currentTarget: WebSocket, eventPhase: 2…}
```

and:

```
CloseEvent {wasClean: false, code: 1006, reason: "", type: "close", target: WebSocket…}
```

I'm using redux and I want to dispatch events along the following lines:

```
ws.onerror = (msg) =>{
    dispatch(error(msg));
};

ws.onclose = (msg) => {
    dispatch(close(msg));
};
```

But I feel I need to have a good understanding of what might get triggered so that I can design my redux states accordingly.